# Согласование в числе. Появилось или появились?

Tags: грамматика

*Большинство обнаруженных на территории некрополя склепов появил**о**сь (так?) в более позднее время.*

Или все же "появил**и**сь"?

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo):

> Согласование сказуемого со словами  «ряд, **большинство**, меньшинство, часть, множество»
>   Выбор правильной формы сказуемого осложняется тем, что опорное слово подлежащего (ряд, большинство, множество и т. п.), представляя собой существительное в форме единственного числа,  фактически означает множество предметов или явлений как совокупность. В этой связи появляются две возможности для согласования сказуемого:
>
> - формально-грамматическое согласование: сказуемое принимает такую же грамматическую форму, как и подлежащее; *большинство граждан проголосовал**о** за нового президента* («большинство» и «проголосовало» – единственное число, средний род); *ряд пользователей отказал**ся** от платной услуги* («ряд» и «отказался» – единственное число, мужской род);
> - согласование по смыслу: сказуемое принимает форму множественного числа, поскольку подлежащее обозначает множество предметов или явлений: *большинство граждан проголосовал**и** за нового президента, ряд пользователей отказал**ись** от платной услуги.*
>
> В современном русском языке формально-грамматическое согласование сказуемого и согласование по смыслу конкурируют, и в большинстве случаев (но не всегда!) формы единственного и множественного числа сказуемого взаимозаменяемы.

Интересно, что такие же варианты возможны и в английском с собирательными существительными (collective nouns), например *police, team, crowd.* При этом в *британском* английском глагол при этих существительных употребляется, как правило, во *множественном* числе (согласование по смыслу), а в *американском,* наоборот, — в единственном.

Comment: Я бы на месте Грамоты не рискнул на согласование глагола с "рядом" в контексте с _людьми_, когда в прямом смысле они не образуют геометрических рядов (большинство же можно представить себе геометрически). Да, само обобщение "большинства" с "рядом" можно встретить и в других материалах, но здесь https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html от примера употребления с "рядом" сознательно уклонились, сославшись на иную "современную тенденцию".